# I do not understand where I'm wrong in this php code to authenticate users

Tags: php, authentication

This is php code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && (trim($_POST['submit']) == "Login")){ 
  if( !isset($_POST['username']) || $_POST['username']=="" ){
    echo "Attenzione, inserire l' username.";
  }else{
      require_once("dbConnection.php");
      $db_handle = new DBConnection();
      $query = "INSERT INTO studente (Nome, Cognome, Matricola, Username, Codice)
      SELECT Nome, Cognome, Matricola, Username FROM studenti_in_sessione WHERE
      studenti_in_sessione.Username = '" . $_POST["username"] . "'";
      $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
      if(!empty($result)){
          echo  " 
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">  
              swal({  
     title: \'Mail inviata\',  
      text: \"Arriverà un codice all'indirizzo di posta elettronica istituzionale con le istruzioni per accedere.\",  
    type: \'success\',   
   }).then(function () {  
    document.getElementById(\"popup\").style.display = \"block\";  
    document.getElementById(\"view\").style.display = \"none\";  
    })  
              </script>  " ; 
      }else{
           echo " 
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">  
              swal({
  title: \'Errore\',
  text: \"Le credenziali sono sbagliate!\",
  type: \'error\',
})
              </script>  ";
      }
  }
  //$db_handle->disconnectDB();
}
?>
```

This is my html form:

```
<form action="../Slide_upload/database/signIn.php" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="username">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
```

When text is "form" and the input is not empty always returns the warning message
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05pOV.png)

[Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnFaD.png)

I looked and covered the code because maybe I had wrongly written the variables and apparently it did not make any mistakes.

Comment: Short version: everywhere.  Basically every line of that code contains a problem or an attack vector.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com - Learn about SQL injection. YOur code is really unsave and your DB can be hacked in a few seconds without any knowledge.

Comment: Your form input doesn't have a `name` attribute

Comment: Too much issue in each line of code

Answer (score 0):

From first, quick look it seems like you POST on username is empty. Make sure you have the html element name 'username'.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `name` attribute in your form

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
```